# Make a function wait for another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've gone into a project lately that requires two different methods for two different variable, but I need to store both of these values in order to use them in another function.

It's a bit complicated, so let me explain. I've got this switch statement that watches for several numbers: 2,3,13,45

```
var hello;
switch ($variable) {
    case 2:
        //do something irrelevant
        break;
    case 3:
        //do something irrelevant
        break;
    case 13:
        //do something with variable named "hello". Ex.:
        alert(hello);
        break;
    case 45:
        hello = "hello";
        break;
}
```

As you can see, I need to get the value of "hello", before the variable gets a value. I can't change the order, nor I can't change variable declaration, so I have to do something with this setup.

What I thought was to make a function call in 13:

```
function getMyVariable(variable) {
    var v = variable;
    return variable;
}

case 13:
    getMyVariable(hello);
    break;
```

Then of course the function would still return undefined.

What I'd like to do, is to make the function wait for the variable set in 45:

(note that this is just speculation, this code is no way near working)

```
case 45:
    hello = "hello";
    getMyVariable(hello);
    break;

function getMyVariable(variable) {
    //function gets call from case 13
    //if type is undefined, wait for a variable that isn't undefined
    //if variable isn't undefined return the variable
}
```

So basically at first call skip case 13, let case 45 set the variable, then go back to case 13 and execute the code here.
Can you follow me? Tell me if you need more info!

Comment: That's impossible. It's either case 13 or case 45, not both.

Comment: Could you please post the whole script? It's difficult to get the big picture of what you intend to do. What is passing these several numbers into the switch statement, and how? And why can't you just move the `hello = "hello"` assignment to the top, does it actually rely on something that happens in case 45?

Comment: I can't move the assignement, it does rely on something that **only** happens in case 45. Sadly, I can't post code, it's an enterprise project. :(

Comment: And the switch statement is executed twice (in a loop or somehow?) - please post at least that part - and case 13 happens before case 45?

Comment: "make the function wait for the variable set in 45" sounds like the observer pattern.  Check this article.  http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2190-two-examples-of-the-observer-pattern-in-javascript/ Second example might help.

Comment: Can you give us a context for this code? It sounds a bit awkward how you're going about this. We might be able to offer a better solution if we had a better idea at what the overall script does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this needs to be defined somewhere outside that it is preserved
// between calls to the code that contains `switch`
var doThisWhenHelloIsSet = [];

// ...
var hello;
switch ($variable) {
    // ...
    case 13:            
        doThisWhenHelloIsSet.push(function(h) {
            // do something with argument named "h" 
            // (which will have the value of variable named "hello").
            // Ex.:
            alert(h);
        });
        break;
    case 45:
        hello = "hello";
        for (var i = 0; i < doThisWhenHelloIsSet.length; i++) {
            doThisWhenHelloIsSet[i](hello);
        }
        doThisWhenHelloIsSet = [];
        break;
}
```

Note: If you want to only store one next action, then you do not need an array.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I understand but is this what you want?

```
var hello = null;
switch ($variable) {
case 2:
    //do something irrelevant
    break;
case 3:
    //do something irrelevant
    break;
case 13:
    //do something with variable named "hello". Ex.:
    if ( hello !== null) {
       alert(hello);
    }
    break;
case 45:
    hello = "hello";
    break;
```

}

Comment: You probably mean `null`, not `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate the `case` check with your `hello` variable. Check if it's set *with* the check for `$variable === 13`.

```
var hello;
switch (true) {
    case $variable === 2: 
        // blah
        break;
    case $variable === 3:
        // blah
        break;

    // this will get called when $variable is 13, 
    // and hello is not blank anymore
    case !!hello && $variable === 13:
        // do something magical
        break;

    case $variable === 45:
        // set hello somewhere?
        hello = 'hello';
        break;
}
```

If what you meant was to have both the `case 13` and `case 45` logic processed at once, you can always try a fallthrough (though be careful).

```
var hello;
switch ($variable) {
    case 2 : 
        // blah
        break;
    case 3 :
        // blah
        break;

    // notice I switched these last two up
    case 45 :
        hello = 'hello';
        // notice that there's no break statement
        // so the logic flows into the case 13 right after case 45.

    case 13 :
        if (!!hello) {
            // do something magical with hello
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you CAN use the for loop to code a goto in JS using a label, which are target-able when they label a ES5 block. This allows you to optionally repeat a switch (compare and cases) without a wrapper function and recursion.

```
var x=false, y=5;

above: for(;;){ // the GOTO target to jump to mid-switch. 

  switch(y){
   case 3: x=true; break; // done. don't repeat switch 2nd time
   case 5: y=3; continue above; // GOTO back top of switch 
  }

  break above; // don't actually loop
} // end for

alert([x,y]); // shows: true,3
```

AFAIK, it's the only way to "go backwards" and run code several times  w/o a function handle.